# How to create a Spannable TextView in Android that includes two labels with round corners and background color?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

[image: Expected Result]

I have to design the above mentioned UI in android, I tried some approaches with TextView using SpannableString for a single label but didn't achieve what we are expecting. The expected result should have

1. TextView that includes **two label** with **different background color**.
2. Must have **round corners**.
3. Label text should be a bit **larger** than the text.
4. Label should be in **bold**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: for rounded corners you can set textview background an appropriate drawable.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your custom View like this:

1. Add **custom_concatenated_text_view.xml** file to your project layout folder.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:padding="5dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Add ConcatenatedTextView.kt file into your project for a custom view

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.app.scorecarts.R
import com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily
import com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable
import com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel


class ConcatenatedTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val textView1: TextView
    private val textView2: TextView
    private val textView3: TextView

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_concatenated_text_view, this)
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10f)
            .build()

        val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
        shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context,R.color.SecondaryRed));
        // Optional - if you need border around uncomment bellow code
        // shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....));
        textView2.background = shapeDrawable

        val shapeDrawable2 = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
        shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context,R.color.SecondaryGreen));
        textView3.background = shapeDrawable2
    }

    // You can access this method in activity to set texts
    fun setTexts(preText: CharSequence?, label1: CharSequence?, label2: CharSequence?) {
        textView1.text = preText
        textView2.text = label1
        textView3.text = label2
    }
}
```

3. Use in XML file like other Views anywhere in your project

```xml
    <com.packagename.ConcatenatedTextView
        android:id="@+id/concatenatedTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
```

Usage in activity

```kotlin
concatenatedTextView.setTexts("Lorem ipsum is simply a dummy text","DONE","HIGH")
```

[image: Output]

Comment: not working as expected in the case of large text, please check by using a large text that can wrap to 2 or 3 lines