# Android: Not receive event for UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED status

Tags: android, kotlin, usbmanager

I'm currently facing an issue in my Android app related to USB device detachment. I have a screen (SetupPrinterActivity) that is supposed to open when a USB device is attached and detached. The attachment part is working fine, but the detachment isn't triggering the expected behavior.

Here's a snippet from `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory" />
    <!-- Add any other registered permissions here -->

    <!-- Features -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.setupprinter.SetupPrinterActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar">

            <!-- Intent Filters -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Meta Data -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Add any other registered activities, services, providers here -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The USB attachment works as expected, and SetupPrinterActivity opens. However, when detaching the USB device from another screen, the expected behavior does not occur.

Here's a snippet from my `SetupPrinterActivity.xml`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    initReceiver()
}

private fun initReceiver() {
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for USB events
    usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.i(tag, "onReceive usbReceiver")
            try {
                when (intent?.action) {
                    UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED -> {
                        // USB device attached
                        Log.i("CHKI", "onReceive usbReceiver ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED")
                        val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                        Log.d(tag, "USB RECEIVER Attached: ${device?.deviceName}")

                        if (device != null) {
                            onUSBAttach(device.deviceName)
                        }
                    }
                    UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED -> {
                        // USB device detached
                        Log.i("CHKI", "onReceive usbReceiver ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED")
                        val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                        Log.d(tag, "USB RECEIVER Detached: ${device?.deviceName}")

                        if (device != null) {
                            onUSBDetach(device.deviceName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("CHKI", "Exception in BroadcastReceiver onReceive: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    // Register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent filters
    val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)
        addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)
    }
    registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter)
}
```

**Here's the current behavior of my app:**

- When I attach a USB device from another screen, the app opens the SetupPrinterActivity and calls the onCreate method, which is the expected behavior.

**Now, here's what I'm expecting for USB detachment:**

- Similar to USB attachment, when I detach the USB device from another screen, I expect the app to open the SetupPrinterActivity and call the onCreate method. However, this behavior is not currently happening.

**Behavior of Broadcast receiver:**

- Broadcast receiver callbacks (attach USB and detach USB) only works when when the SetupPrinterActivity is open, otherwise calls the `onCreate` method if it is closed.

Has anyone faced a similar issue before, where USB detachment does not trigger the expected behavior. Please help me and Thanks in advance for read my issue.

I followed the official documentation while implementation: [USB host overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626106/how-to-create-a-spannable-textview-in-android-that-includes-two-labels-with-roun)